# how to get buckets count in elasticsearch aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to get how many buckets on an aggregation in specific datetime range,

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
  "filtered_aggs": {
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "datetime": {
        "gte": "2017-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
         "lte": "2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "addr": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "region",
         "size": 10000
       }
     }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

output:

```
  "took" : 317,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "num_reduce_phases" : 3,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1118,
    "successful" : 1118,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1899658551,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
     "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "filtered_aggs" : {
      "doc_count" : 88,
      "addr" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "NY",
            "doc_count" : 36
           },
          {
            "key" : "CA",
            "doc_count" : 13
          },
          {
            "key" : "JS",
            "doc_count" : 7
        ..........
```

Is there a way to return both requests (buckets + total bucket count) in one search?
I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5.0 
Can I get all of them?

Comment: Make size very big if u want all the results

Comment: I have try to set size from 0 to 10000, but didn't get any results

Comment: And you are sure  you have data in that time?

Comment: I find the error, it's my fault,I set the wrong field datetime ,It's should @timestamp

Comment: now,work success , but how to get the total aggregation bucket counts ?